# Increasing number of artificial images generated with DCGAN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dcgan

I am actually working with DCGAN (Py-Torch implementation), and the output is always a 64-sized grid of artificial images per epoch. I would like to increase such number, but do not know (I do not know which parameter to change, but I tried to check the code without success).
Does anyone have some idea of how to do that?

The entire Py-Torch implementation of DCGAN can be found in the following link:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this value of below parameters to whatever the size of image you would want as output

## Size of feature maps in generator

ngf = 64

## Size of feature maps in discriminator

ndf = 64